# Calling a feature and passing in javascript variables

Tags: karate

Been trying to figure this out for a while, please could someone help.
I have a set of 5 lines which I'd like to make reusable.
The lines do a "check event XXX has fired".
The lines make use of the "karate" variable and also the "json" command.
They're of the form:

```
* def message = myUtils.grabEvent(karate, myMessageListener)
* json event = message.text
* match event contains { ... some json in here ... }
* json eventPayload = event.payload
* match event contains { ... some payload json in here ... }
```

How do I go about making this reusable?
I have tried:
(A) Putting it all into a Javascript function
This failed because I don't know how to replicate the "json" command in Javascript
(B) Putting it all into a .feature file and calling that
This failed because I don't know how to pass the "karate" and "myMessageListener" variables into parameters of the .feature file.

Is it possible to put this into a reusable code block, please?

TIA

Answer (score -2):

Yes I would recommend making this a reusable feature. Refer the documentation here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files

And passing parameters is simple it would look like:

```
* def result = call read('reusable.feature')
```

Because by default, the "called" feature will "inherit" the variables of the calling feature.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Peter. I can't do this because "myMessageListener" might be called something else in the calling code. Can I pass in argument list to the .feature file somehow?

Comment: yes. read the docs. `call read('reusable.feature') { myMessageListener: '#(somethingElse)' }`

Comment: Thanks, might have got it working now - will confirm tomorrow and update this question

Comment: If you could edit your answer above I'll certainly mark it as accepted. I don't think the docs are clear on this. The quotes in your comment above make it look (to me at least) like the variable values will be treated as strings. Thanks for the help though, much appreciated.

Comment: PS should karate.prevRequest be carried over into the called .feature file? I am finding I'm going to have to pass my "outer" karate into the called .feature so the logic can grab a prevRequest header value

Comment: @davidfrancis I think you should spend more time reading the docs, or perhaps someone else more qualified can help you. the only advice I have left is this: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I thought you developed Karate so were the most qualified possible? I'll put together a complete example and submit it on that link! I can work around it for now by passing in the outer karate instance

Comment: @davidfrancis I have tried my best to write reasonable docs, so I'm looking to expert users like you to suggest improvements :P